# Kubernetes wait that apiVersion and kind exists before trying to apply resource using those

Tags: kubernetes

How can I check and/or wait that apiVersion and kind exists before trying to apply resource using those?

**Example:**

*Install cilium and network policy using cilium*

```
kubectl apply -f cilium.yaml
kubectl apply -f policy.yaml # fails if run just after installing cilium, since cilium.io/v2 and CiliumNetworkPolicy doesn't exist yet
```

[*cilium.yaml*](https://github.com/cilium/cilium/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/1.13/cilium.yaml)

*policy.yaml*

```
apiVersion: cilium.io/v2
description: example policy
kind: CiliumNetworkPolicy
...
```

**EDIT:** *(solved with following script)*

```
#! /bin/bash

function check_api {
    local try=0
    local retries=30
    until (kubectl "api-$1s" | grep -P "\b$2\b") &>/dev/null; do
        (( ++try > retries )) && exit 1
        echo "$2 not found. Retry $try/$retries"
        sleep 3
    done
}

kubectl apply -f cilium.yaml
check_api version cilium.io/v2
check_api resource CiliumNetworkPolicy
kubectl apply -f policy.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to check for supported versions and kinds, that is, check what the API server you're talking to supports:

```
$ kubectl api-versions
admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
...
storage.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1
```

There's also `kubectl api-resources` that provides you with a tabular overview of the kinds, shortnames, and if a resource is namespaced or not.

Comment: so something like this should work, or is there better ways?
https://bpaste.net/show/0f0c19aaca98

Comment: Yup, LGTM. Also, if the answer addresses your question, please accept it as the correct one so that people coming after you know about it as well.